# Why can't I insert a string into a TKinter entry?

Tags: python, tkinter, pickle

I'm making a sort of shopping list type of program in Python (3.7, on windows, with TKinter), specifically designed for hardware synths setups. Think PC part picker, but for a synth setup.

It saves the users choice of each component in a dictionary. Then, when the user presses the save button, it uses the pickle library to save the dictionary to a file. When they open the app again, it loads the dictionary from the file, and it *should* set the contents of all the entry boxes to the corresponding value in the dictionary. It worked fine, but then I added another category for the user to enter into and it stopped working.

Here is the code:

```
#import libraries
from tkinter import *
import pickle

win=Tk() #create window
win.title("Synth Planner") #set title
win.configure(bg="#010") #set background
win.geometry("1200x675") #set size

savedict={"seq":"", "seq$":"","synth1":"","synth1$":"","synth2":"","synth2$":""}

def save(): #when save btn pressed
    #save all entries to dict
    savedict["seq"]=txtSeq.get()
    savedict["seq$"]=txtSeqPrice.get()
    savedict["synth1"]=txtSynth1.get()
    savedict["synth1$"]=txtSynth1Price.get()
#this is the line causing the error:
    savedict["synth2"]=txtSynth2.get()
#^
    savedict["synth2$"]=txtSynth2Price.get()

    #save dict to file
    with open("data","wb") as savefile: #open file
        pickle.dump(savedict,savefile) #use pickle to save dict
    
#create components
lblTitle=Label(win,font=("Trebuchet MS",28),text="Synth Planner",bg="#010",fg="#fff") #title
btnSave=Button(win,font=("Trebuchet MS",12),text="Save",command=save) #save button
lblPrice=Label(win,font=("Trebuchet MS",12),text="Price",bg="#010",fg="#fff") #price label
lblSeq=Label(win,font=("Trebuchet MS",12),text="Sequencer",bg="#010",fg="#fff") #sequencer label
txtSeq=Entry(win,font=("Trebuchet MS",12),bg="#fff",fg="#010") #sequencer entry
txtSeqPrice=Entry(win,font=("Trebuchet MS",12),bg="#fff",fg="#010",width=10) #seq price
lblSynth1=Label(win,font=("Trebuchet MS",12),text="Synth",bg="#010",fg="#fff") #synth 1 label
txtSynth1=Entry(win,font=("Trebuchet MS",12),text="Synth",bg="#fff",fg="#010") #synth 1 entry
txtSynth1Price=Entry(win,font=("Trebuchet MS",12),bg="#fff",fg="#010",width=10) #synth 1 price entry
lblSynth2=Label(win,font=("Trebuchet MS",12),text="Synth",bg="#010",fg="#fff") #synth 2 label
txtSynth2=Entry(win,font=("Trebuchet MS",12),text="Synth",bg="#fff",fg="#010") #synth 2 entry
txtSynth2Price=Entry(win,font=("Trebuchet MS",12),bg="#fff",fg="#010",width=10) #synth 2 price entry

#set all text inputs to previous user inputs, by reading pickle file
with open("data","rb") as savefile: #open file
    savedict=pickle.load(savefile) #load file into dict
#set all entries
txtSeq.insert(0,savedict.get("seq"))
txtSeqPrice.insert(0,savedict.get("seq$"))
txtSynth1.insert(0,savedict.get("synth1"))
txtSynth1Price.insert(0,savedict.get("synth1$"))
txtSynth2.insert(0,savedict.get("synth2"))
txtSynth2Price.insert(0,savedict.get("synth2$"))

#place components
lblTitle.place(x=600,y=20,anchor=N)
btnSave.place(x=1150,y=30,anchor=N)
lblPrice.place(x=300,y=50,anchor=N)
lblSeq.place(x=10,y=80)
txtSeq.place(x=90,y=82)
txtSeqPrice.place(x=270,y=82)
lblSynth1.place(x=10,y=120)
txtSynth1.place(x=90,y=122)
txtSynth1Price.place(x=270,y=122)
lblSynth2.place(x=10,y=160)
txtSynth2.place(x=90,y=162)
txtSynth2Price.place(x=270,y=162)

win.mainloop #keep the window open until closed by user
```

Here's the error message:

```
in insert
    self.tk.call(self._w, 'insert', index, string)
_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be ".!entry5 insert index text"
```

The method I'm using to insert the text worked fine in the lines above, which do the same thing.

Please let me know if I'm supposed to provide any other information. I don't post on here very often.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is any issue. I worked perfectly fine for me. Please provide complete error message, from trackback to last

Comment: Please provide the whole traceback

Comment: Where does the error happen?

Comment: I had to replace win.mainloop with win.mainloop(), then it worked ok.

Comment: You will get this error if the value you are trying to insert is `None`. My guess is, your save file has a `None` value in it.